# Is a subclass instance valid where a class instance is expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say we have the following:

```
class MyClass:
    pass

def my_function(class_instance_argument: MyClass):
    pass
```

If I'm writing a piece of code and want to indicate the type of object that should be passed, I could do just that. However, if I further extend my code in another file:

```
class MyClass2(MyClass):
    pass
```

I am not sure whether a subclass instance would be a valid data type where a class instance is expected. I know annotations are not binding; in fact, if I want to be able to assert that the passed argument is as of my desire, I would do:

```
assert(issubclass(type(class_instance_argument), MyClass)))
```

And this would work for any subclass, even for a class with itself:

```
>>> issubclass(type, type)
True
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can pass a `MyClass2` instance to `my_function`? Yes. Also, `isinstance(class_instance_argument, MyClass)` is the usual way to write `issubclass(type(class_instance_argument), MyClass))`.

Comment: @Ry- does isinstance also apply to mother classes then? I think that is basically the same question in fact

Comment: To be honest I'm not really sure what the question is. Are you aware of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which states that you can use an instance of a subclass everywhere an instance of a parent class is expected?

Comment: @Aran-Fey the question is not extremely clear because there is something I fail to understand, but I guessed that would be deduced by someone that does know that thing I don't.

Comment: @Aran-Fey In fact the link you provided is pretty much what I needed to know I thknk

Comment: As far as `isinstance` goes… you could just try it. (You could try the original question, too, with mypy.)

Comment: I am sorry if I did not explain the question in the proper way; however I don't think that deserves a downvote as far as that is due to of the lack of knowledge about my question. Having a difficulty identifying a proper question does not mean I did not make an effort in explaining it clearly.

Comment: Downvote functionality: "This question does not show enough research effort, it is unclear (except to you), or not helpful for anybody else". I think that someone aware of that _Liskov substitution principle_ would perfectly understand that I could not quite ask it better because I din't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: No. You don't have to do anything.

Subtyping means substitutability. In other words, if `MyClass2` is a subtype of `MyClass`, any `MyClass2` acts properly like a `MyClass`. Or, put another way, you can use a `MyClass2` value in any code that expects a `MyClass`, and it will work, even if that code has never heard of `MyClass2`. Wikipedia has a more detailed article on the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) if you want to get into the details of what "acts properly like" really means.<sup>1</sup>

So, when you annotate that this function requires a `MyClass`, that means that a `MyClass2` is acceptable, because a `MyClass2` really is a `MyClass`.

---

It's worth reading [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), the proposal that added type-hinting syntax, and the other PEPs linked from the top. In fact, this question is covered right near the top, under [Type Declaration Syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-definition-syntax):

> Expressions whose type is a subtype of a specific argument type are also accepted for that argument.

---

Now, Python doesn't actually force your subclasses to be subtypes. It strongly encourages it, but if you want to write a subclass that overrides methods with an incompatible signature (or even hides them behind a `__getattribute__`), you can, and you will fool any reasonable static type checker.

But as long as you don't actually go out of your way to fool the type checker, things will work as you'd expect. (And if you *do* go out of your way… well, presumably you had a reason to do that, and things will work as you explicitly force them to work instead.)

---

Python itself is built around the idea of duck typing—it doesn't matter if an object actually is an instance of some type, only that it provides the right attributes with the right behavior—informally, that it "quacks like a `MyClass`", or more formally that it "conforms to the `MyClass` protocol".

You might think that this is a poor fit for static type checking. But, as it turns out, it works pretty well. For one thing, type hints are always optional.<sup>2</sup> But when you want to explicitly check a duck-typed function, there's usually a pretty easy way to write a structural protocol-checking type—if there isn't already one in the `typing` module. For example, instead of requiring a `list`, you can require a `Sequence`, and that will match a `tuple` or a `range` or some custom sequence type that some user of your library invented that you never heard of, as long as it meets the protocol for `Sequence`. (While we're at it, you can also require a `Sequence[int]`, which will accept a `list` or a `tuple` or a `MySillySequence`, but only if the type checker can prove that it contains nothing but `int` values.)

---

<sub>1. AFAIK, Python's documentation, including the set of PEPs, deliberately avoid referring to the LSP. The LSP is a somewhat loose way of describing subtyping, and PEP 484 relies on a way of describing subtyping that's somewhat loose in slightly different ways. It's already a bit odd to use formal terms like "upper bound of the subtype tree" without ever defining "subtype", but it pretty much works; implying that the subtype tree was actually defined by the LSP might mean it isn't quite accurate.</sub>

<sub>2. And this really is important. Some protocols are easy to use, but hard to define, and the fact that you can just punt and say `Any` even in a program that's otherwise completely annotated means you can otherwise completely annotate the program, and run a type checker on it (and even see where that loose typing "leaks out" to the rest of your code and where it doesn't).</sub>

Comment: asAlso, following up, that does mean that type enforcement is not a recommended practice in Python? I mean, that would presumably cause more difficultly debuggable errors as exceptions would not clearly indicate that the object is not the expected type but that it does not behave in a certain aspect _as_ the expected type.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde Type enforcement as in checking arguments' types at runtime? That's _generally_ not recommended, but sometimes it's useful. And in the cases when it is needed, you _usually_ want to do it with `isinstance` with an abstract base class, but not always. But the question of exactly when it is and isn't acceptable is one of those questions that will get you a holy war rather than an objective answer, unless you're happy with something as vague as "more than never, but nowhere near as often as you'd expect if you're coming from Java".

Comment: Especially in very long or complex pieces of code, to find the reason why _this or that_ specific object inside the function does _not have_ property _whatever_ is not very self-explanatory if you can put it like that, imo

Comment: btw, is your quote a thing?

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde First, to make very long pieces of code understandable, you usually want to break them up into smaller pieces of code. That also—not entirely coincidentally—means that you now have interfaces (function parameters or object attributes), where you can add type hints, which can be even more useful to a human reader than to a static type checker.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde In fact, the main reason PEP 484 happened was that Guido was leading a project to port a big hunk of code from Python 2.7 to 3.4 and wanted to be able to annotate Unicode strings vs. byte strings, and, as I understand it, the benefit to team members reading each other's code was at least as important as the ability to mechanically verify that they got it right.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde Finally, which quote?

Comment: The Java joke ;) Thank you for the explanation, it has been very helpful. I will try to adhere to those guidelines when writing new code.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde That exact quote isn't a thing, but "… if you're coming from Java"  in general kind of is. It's not as big a problem as it was during the period when many universities were transitioning from Java to Python for most undergrad CS classes (so a lot of students were learning a bit of Java and then jumping suddenly to Python next semester, while others were learning from professors who'd themselves just learned Python over the winter break…), but it still comes up.